# What conditions may cause "The content on this page has either been modified by another user..."?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm working on a website which has multiple admins, some creating contents, some editing and some tagging...

I know editing one node at the same time will cause this error, is there anything else cause this error?

> The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess, maybe it could be caused by Revisions. When 2 admins start editing same revision, then one saves it, goes OK, the other tries to save it after, but the revision he started editing is already out of date.

Comment: Is there any way to disable edit links for second admin while there is an open edit form?

Comment: A bit late but yes, http://drupal.org/project/content_lock allows to lock nodes which are currently being edited.

Comment: not late, its an open question for me, yet. tnx

Comment: Related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163331/how-can-you-remove-the-edit-lock-on-a-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another cause might me the fact that you save a form, then hit the back button and try to save it again

Comment: Yes this case already mentioned in error `...or you have already submitted modifications using this form...`, do you think is any other case?

Answer (score 1):

I just managed to create this error with a FireFox setting.  I told FF never to save history and cleared my browser cache and then could not submit changes to nodes.  When I turned 'save history' back on, the issue resolved.  Probably related to a change in how FF was handling cookies.

Site is Drupal 7 with OpenPublish, IDK much more than that as I'm new to the project.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is related to two users editing the same record (node), it can be related to max_input_vars in your php.ini

There are two solutions to solve the problem (I recommend trying both of them):

1. Edit phpi.ini and increase max_input_vars (find max_input_vars = ... and increase it). php.ini can be found in different locations for example in an ubuntu conventional setup it can be at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
2. Clear cache (depend on your browser this is a pretty easy routine and you already do not know it, just google it).

Check https://www.drupal.org/node/1933120

Answer (score 0):

I got this error across my entire site and I'm not sure of the root cause.

If I edited and saved a page and then clicked the edit tab to edit the page and tried to save again, I would get the error.

I was banging my head against the wall trying to fix it until I fixed it by rebuilding the site permissions: admin/reports/status/rebuild

Another solution that others pointed to was to increase the max_input_vars in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to Maximum Input Variable Limit. You can use a module to control it. [PHP Runtime Configurator](https://www.drupal.org/project/change_file_upload_limit) module provides many options to configure without changing your php.ini file and restart Apache.

You can configure following parameters:

- File Upload Limit
- Memory Limit
- Maximum Execution Time Limit
- Maximum Input Variable Limit