# Node won't edit or publish

Tags: 7, nodes

The node has about 200 photos in an image field. Clicking remove on the image doesn't do anything, it gives image that it was removed, but it wasn't, on second try it gives error.

> The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or
>   you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result,
>   your changes cannot be saved.

What I've tried:

1. Logged out all users, so nobody is editing any content `drush sql-query 'TRUNCATE TABLE sessions;'`
2. Tried `sql-query 'TRUNCATE TABLE cache_form;'`
3. Edited php.ini and increased `max_input_vars` to `3000` as per [How can you remove the edit lock on a node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163331/how-can-you-remove-the-edit-lock-on-a-node)
4. And tried the rest from that thread.
5. I did rebuild the permissions and cleared caches.
6. No errors in log.

It doesn't matter if you try to create new content, it saves on first save and you can't edit it. It also gets saved as unpublished, even if ticked published.

The only way to make the publishing work is via `admin/content` with some views module that gives some bulk operations.

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible MySQL stopped responding or that the node is having trouble processing the form (due to so many fields present)?

Comment: @Kevin so what would be the solution? The server's too slow?

Comment: I think its possible you might have some server logs (that aren't in Drupal) that may have more information around this. I know that when I have a form with lots of Paragraphs, I experience something similar. This would explain why using bulk actions to save works, because theres no giant node form structure to process on submit. Just a thought. But you mention it happens on brand new nodes too, so, maybe that is not it.